# Oracle - Search for Word within a Word

Tags: sql, string, oracle, search, plsql

I'm hoping there is a brain out there that would kind enough to help a lost soul;

I have two columns; `COL_A` and `COL_B`, each record for both columns only contains one word (the length of the word can vary).

What I'm trying to do is search `COL_A` and identify a partial (word) match with `COL_B`, for example, `COL_A = 'MSOFT'`, `COL_B = 'MICROSOFT'` therefore this would be classified as a match.

Likewise, if `COL_A = 'RANGE'` and `COL_B = 'ORANGE'` this would also be classified as a match.

However, if `COL_A = 'ORGAN'` and `COL_B = 'ORANGE'` this would not be classified as a match.

I'm open to suggestions (pure SQL, Function, etc.).

As always, any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It is still not clear what you mean by a match. So if col_A = 'RANGE' and col_B = 'ORANGE' that is a match; is it still a match if col_A = 'ORANGE' and col_B = 'RANGE'? Does it matter which is a sub-word of the other? Then: does the difference between the two words have to be a contiguous substring (as in all your examples), or does 'ALMA' match 'K**AL**I**M**ER**A**'?

Comment: Hi Mathguy, apologies for the ambiguity; COL_A will always contain less than or the same number of characters as COL_B. Regarding the string; yes, it will be a contiguous substring (therefore ‘ALMA’ and ‘KALIMERA’ would not be considered a match. Many thanks.

Comment: OK, so a match means the first row is either an initial substring, a final substring (meaning anchored at the end), or the concatenation of an initial substring followed by a final substring? Any other situation means that the "difference" is not contiguous. Please confirm. Then: Interesting problem! Not sure how applicable it really is in real life, but it's a nice challenge (non-trivial because there are several ways to match).

Comment: Indeed, interesting - it’s been giving me brain ache for the past few hours. In theory it could be a concatenation of both... That said, I believe taking the final substring would be a good starting point.

Comment: So, just to be clear - "false positives" (in text matching) are sometimes called the "mother is in che**mother**apy" problem (for the reason I highlighted). However, according to our rules this is NOT A MATCH, because the difference is made up of two disconnected strings, 'che' at the beginning and 'apy' at the end. Just making sure...

Comment: The interesting life of working with strings - I’m looking forward to getting back to numbers. Again, thanks for all your help - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.. which will work for your sample data

```
SELECT *
  FROM yourtable
WHERE INSTR(col_a,col_b,1)>0
   OR INSTR(col_b,col_a,1)>0
   or INSTR(substr(col_a,2,length(col_a)), col_b,1)>0
   or INSTR(substr(col_b,2,length(col_b)), col_a,1)>0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplistic way to solve this. It's not pretty, and it is probably not efficient (but the problem itself may not have very efficient solutions, by its nature). It should be easy to read, understand and maintain though.

I assume NULL in col_a is treated as "empty string" and therefore it matches col_b regardless of what is in col_b. If instead you want to treat it as an actual NULL, you can either return 'N' or perhaps, better yet, NULL, in the `MATCH` column.

```
with
     inputs ( col_a, col_b ) as (
       select 'MSOFT', 'MICROSOFT' from dual union all
       select 'RANGE', 'ORANGE'    from dual union all
       select 'BLUES', 'BLUES'     from dual union all
       select 'ORGAN', 'ORANGE'    from dual union all
       select 'ALMA' , 'KALIMERA'  from dual union all
       select null   , 'OCTOPUS'   from dual union all
       select 'ALPHA', 'ALPHABET'  from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select col_a, col_b,
       case when col_a is null then 'Y'
            when exists ( select level from dual
                          where col_a = substr( col_b, 1, level - 1 ) || 
                                          substr( col_b, -(length(col_a) - level + 1),
                                                           length(col_a) - level + 1 )
                          connect by level <= length(col_a) + 1
                        )
                               then 'Y'
                               else 'N' end as match
from  inputs;

COL_A COL_B     M
----- --------- -
MSOFT MICROSOFT Y
RANGE ORANGE    Y
BLUES BLUES     Y
ORGAN ORANGE    N
ALMA  KALIMERA  N
      OCTOPUS   Y
ALPHA ALPHABET  Y
```

Comment: Thanks, Mathguy - this looks like it will do the job. Awesome! You’re a star!

Answer (score 0):

A simple `like` condition should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  col_a LIKE '%' || col_b || '%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the very prompt response, Mureinik. I did try using the above but unfortunately it didn’t appear to satisfy my requirements. I think (and I could be wrong) but based on my testing, this only works for whole words as opposed to partial words (e.g. if COL_A = ‘SOFT’ and COL_B = ‘MICROSOFT’ it would match, but not if COL_A = ‘MSOFT’). Whereas I would need ‘MSOFT’ to count as a match.

Comment: See also my Comment to the OP - did I miss something, or are you just guessing at the full requirement with this solution?